# Readable way to concat many strings in java

Tags: java, string

I have some code written in a very cryptic fashion. It is sure going to be a maintenance nightmare for anyone other than me to understand.

Its a mishmash of string concatenation, ternary operator and concatenating using `+` operator.

So my question is how would I make this statement readable?

```
tb.setTally_narration(
     tb.getTally_mode().equals("Ca") ? 
        "Receipt No. "
             .concat(tb.getTally_receipt_no())
             .concat(", "+tb.getTally_mode()) : 
        "Receipt No. "
             .concat(tb.getTally_receipt_no()+", "+tb.getTally_mode())
             .concat(", "+tb.getTally_instrument_no()+", "+tb.getTally_instrument_date()+", "+tb.getTally_instrument_bank())
);
```

Edit: I realize this question is subjective. And I feel it belongs to codereview stackexchange site. Could it be moved there?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Use the printf-style `String.format`.

Comment: Will use that and post back my experience. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only place that `setTally_narration` is used?

Comment: Not sure what's the use case but did you consider avoiding code repetition by placing this in a method and use some recursion? There must be a flag that you can use to tell the program to stop appending stuff and return the final result.

Comment: Using a standard "if" statement, rather than a ternary operartor, would make it more "readable".

Comment: It might be a situation that calls for a templating framework, e.g. [Mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java).

Comment: @Henrik a dependency to a whole framework for one usage? That seems overkill to me.

Comment: @Fildor: Agreed, but how did you infer that it's only a single usage?

Comment: Something along these lines, http://ideone.com/YBBvQz , by breaking every atomic part in .append() I assume. Will report back String.format soon.

Comment: Actually wanted to use StringBuilder but I suupose StringBuffer serves the same purpose

Comment: @Henrik I have to, because the OP is not complaining about having "hundreds of statements like this one" ... Not sure if I can, of course. If he did have more, then a framework would be the way to go, I agree in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the first line of the string appears to be the same, I would write it simply as:

```
StringBuilder narration = new StringBuilder("Receipt No. ");

narration.append(tb.getTally_receipt_no())
         .append(", ").append(tb.getTally_mode());
if (!"Ca".equals(tb.getTally_mode()))
{
    narration.append(", ").append(tb.getTally_instrument_no())
             .append(", ").append(tb.getTally_instrument_date())
             .append(", ").append(tb.getTally_instrument_bank());
}

tb.setTally_narration(narration.toString());
```

Comment: `.append(", " + ...)` is not a good practice, use `.append(", ").append(...)` instead.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Yes, good point (thanks!).  I was being lazy and mixing them since I copied and pasted, but if I am going to post an answer might as well make it correct.

Comment: This looks good. But then again I am not much experienced. Also, can all these narration instances be chained with many .append() calls like `narration.append("this").append("that")` instead of `narration.append("this");narration.append("that")`

Comment: @Ahsan They can indeed be, and already are in the case of the `", "` followed by the variable.  I will update the rest to use more chaining, saves some typing!

Answer (score 4):

Lots of choices here, but if maintainability is your goal (as it usually should), then be a little more verbose.

- Use if-then rather than ?:
- Use + rather than concat()
- Use a temporary variable or two (which the compiler will optimize away)

So:

```
String narration = "Receipt No.";

if (tb.getTally_mode().equals("Ca")) {
    narration += tb.getTally_receipt_no() 
              +  ", "
              +  tb.getTally_mode();
} else {
    narration += tb.getTally_receipt_no()
              +  ", "
              +  tb.getTally_mode()
              +  ", "
              +  tb.getTally_instrument_no()
              +  ", "
              +  tb.getTally_instrument_date()
              +  ", "
              +  tb.getTally_instrument_bank();
}

tb.setTally_narration(narration);
```

Comment: Not bad, Nick. But still some duplication. Note that the first part is always the same, so we could build that part unconditionally and add the second only if the `...equals("Ca")` is not true.

Answer (score 4):

```
  String rNum    = tb.getTallyReceiptNum();
  String mode    = tb.getTallyMode();
  String iNum    = tb.getTallyInstrumentNum();
  String iDate   = tb.getTallyInstrumentDate();
  String iBank   = tb.getTallyInstrumentBank();

  String narration = String.format("Receipt No. %s, %s", rNum, mode);

  if(! "Ca".equals(mode)){
    narration = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s", narration, iNum, iDate, iBank);
  }
```

1. Methods names in Java's format.
2. `String.format()` allows formatting changes in future.
3. call `equals()` on a non null String ( "Ca" ), reduce chances of a possible NPE.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!"Ca".equals(mode))` ?

Comment: @Fildor ah.. of course.